# Calling WebService Using AJAX jQuery With SOAP

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, web-services, soap

I'm copy/pasting this HTML code [from this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/calling-webservice-using-ajax-jquery-with-soap-message-creat/) but I cannot make the service work.

The article talks about a WebService used to do simple arithmetic calculation, and I was lucky enought to find an endpoint that provides the same service:

http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL

So I fire up WcfStorm and if I try to request a SOAP call that makes `3 + 5` I receive as result `8`:

[image]

All good, so now let's inject the call:

```
<Add>
  <MethodParameters>
    <intA>3</intA>
    <intB>5</intB>
  </MethodParameters>
</Add>
```

Into the HTML code that I find in the article:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#BTNSERVICE").click(function (event) {
                var webserUrl = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL";
                var soapRequest =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<Add> \
  <MethodParameters> \
    <intA>0</intA> \
    <intB>0</intB> \
  </MethodParameters> \
</Add> \
</soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: webserUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: SuccessOccur,
                    error: ErrorOccur
                });
            });
        });
        function SuccessOccur(data, status, req) {
            if (status == "success")
                alert(req.responseText);
        }
        function ErrorOccur(data, status, req) {
            alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:button id="BTNSERVICE" runat="server" text="BTNSERVICE" />
    SAMPLE Application to test service
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I save he file as an .HTML file and I open if with FireFox but no joy:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'm literally following the guide step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your **soapRequest**, exactly this line:

```
<Add> \
```

Opening this url **http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add** you can see your **Add** method is:

```
<Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

Indeed, the error message you receive is:

```
Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.
```

The snippet:

```js
// the following in order to handle cors in this demo....
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        options.url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    }
});

$("#BTNSERVICE").click(function (event) {
    var intA = $('#intA').val();
    var intB = $('#intB').val();

    var soapRequest = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                       <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                            <soap:Body>
                                <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                                    <intA>${intA}</intA>
                                    <intB>${intB}</intB>
                                </Add>
                            </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>`;

    var webserUrl = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL";
    var self = this;
    self.disabled = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webserUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        data: soapRequest,
        success: function (data, status, req) {
            if (status == "success") {
                var result = $(req.responseXML).find('AddResult').text();
                $('#AddResult').val(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, req) {
            $('#errmsg').text(data.responseText);
        },
        complete: function(data, status) {
            self.disabled = false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form runat="server">
    intA: <input id="intA" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    intB: <input id="intB" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    AddResult: <input id="AddResult" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    <button id="BTNSERVICE"  type="button">SAMPLE Application to test service</button>
</form>
<div id="errmsg"></div>
```

A minimal html file containing the code follows. You can see in it where and how I added js and html form element:

1. in the header section you can see how I added the jQuery library and the js code
2. in the body section you can see the form element with input fields and a button.

The following is the minimal html file containing only the js code and html tags you can use.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <!-- in the header section you can add javascript -->

    <!-- include the jQuery library version 3.3.1 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- include javascript code -->
    <script>
        // the following in order to handle cors in this demo....
        // for details see: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation
        jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
            if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
                options.url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
            }
        });

        // on DOM ready...
        $(function () {
            // the following event handler will handle click events for BUTTON
            $("#BTNSERVICE").on('click', function (event) {
                var intA = $('#intA').val();
                var intB = $('#intB').val();

                var soapRequest = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soap:Body>
                            <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                                <intA>${intA}</intA>
                                <intB>${intB}</intB>
                            </Add>
                        </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>`;

                var webserUrl = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL";
                var self = this;
                self.disabled = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: webserUrl,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: function (data, status, req) {
                        if (status == "success") {
                            var result = $(req.responseXML).find('AddResult').text();
                            $('#AddResult').val(result);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, req) {
                        $('#errmsg').text(data.responseText);
                    },
                    complete: function (data, status) {
                        self.disabled = false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>


<!-- in the body section you can add form -->
<form runat="server">
    intA: <input id="intA" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    intB: <input id="intB" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    AddResult: <input id="AddResult" type="text" value="0"> <br>
    <button id="BTNSERVICE" type="button">SAMPLE Application to test service</button>
</form>
<div id="errmsg"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is working @gaetanoM, where should I paste that JS file, inside the HTML itself? On a separate file? I need precise instructions, please. Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Answer updated. I added a minimal html file with comments describing where you need to put each element. By default you can copy everything like it is in a local file with a suffix .html and open it with a browser.  If this is not sufficient let me know how can I help you. See the comments in the last snippet. Thanks